# image rotation method leaves something in the ram

Tags: java, memory, bufferedimage, affinetransform

I am currently working on a game and for more diversity of graphics I want to call a rotate(BufferedImage imgOld, int deg) method a few hundred times to rotate some graphics (eg. tree stumps).

With unrotated graphics I never had any issues with memory. But as soon as I started to use the rotator the error occurred if I didn't reduce the amount of rotated images drastically (like 95% drastically).

The error always occurred inside of the rotate(BufferedImage imgOld, int deg) method and only since I started to rotate massive amounts of images so I suppose there must be some leftovers inside the memory from the rotate(BufferedImage imgOld, int deg) method I don't know how to deal with.

Here you see the code of the class Rotator:

```
package movement;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Rotator {
    public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage imgOld, int deg){                                                                              //Parameters for the method are the image to rotate and the rate of rotation in degrees
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(deg), (int)(imgOld.getWidth()/2), (int)(imgOld.getHeight()/2));       //setting up the transform
        BufferedImage imgNew = new BufferedImage(imgOld.getWidth(), imgOld.getHeight(), imgOld.getType());                                          //creating a new image with the same properties of the old one
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) imgNew.getGraphics();                                                                                           //create my graphics
        g.setTransform(at);                                                                                                                         //applying the transform
        g.drawImage(imgOld, 0, 0, null);                                                                                                            //painting rotated image
        return imgNew;                                                                                                                              //return rotated image              
    }       
}
```

I hope somebody has an idea and i didn't make any mistakes (its my first question posted here).

Comment: Are you maintaining references to the returned rotated images (e.g., storing them in an array)?

Comment: Yes I save the returned rotated images in objects, which are saved in an array

Comment: But they override the unrotated images which should leave the memory the same

Comment: How about a `g.dispose();` at the end of the method? And using `createGraphics()` makes the type cast to `Graphics2D` obsolete.

Comment: thank you for the fast responses - sadly despite adding `g.dispose()` didn't remove the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest problem is simple- you're duplicating *every* image you're *every* time you rotate. You can try to draw the rotated image back onto itself, removing the need to churn through a massive amount of objects for the garbage collector.

Also, if you are dead-set on making new objects, make sure you flush (`BufferedImage#flush`) the old images and dipose (`Graphics2D#dispose`) the graphics objects.

Comment: But the old image is replaced with the new one. its like `image = Rotator.rotate(image, degrees)` how and where should i flush it ?

Comment: Right before the return statement, call `g.dispose()` and `imgOld.flush()`

Comment: Was the solution of my problem - I' m still getting the error, but only at massive amounts of graphics, which is a lack optimisation. (every image is loaded in the ram althought not all of them are visible on screen) If the optimisation is coded everything should work error-free

Comment: Dunno if this is a problem, but often people accidentally make multiple `BufferedImage`s when one would do just fine. Always remember to have at most one object per image file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong tool for the job. If you want to transform entire images, esp. `BufferedImage`s, you should have a look at [`BufferedImageOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImageOp.html)s and in your case [`AffineTransformOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html).

Then the entire operation may be implemented as

```
public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage imgOld, int deg){
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(
        Math.toRadians(deg), imgOld.getWidth()/2, imgOld.getHeight()/2);
    AffineTransformOp op=new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC);
    BufferedImage imgNew = new BufferedImage(
        imgOld.getWidth(), imgOld.getHeight(), imgOld.getType());
    return op.filter(imgOld, imgNew);
}
```

This doesn’t deal with `Graphics` and such alike. The way your original approach works, is to rotate the original image and draw it onto the destination image by combining the destination’s original content (initially empty) with the rotated data of the source, depending on the `Graphics` blending mode. In contrast, the code above will directly render the transformed picture into the destination, not attempting to preserve existing content.

Note further, that you can pass in an existing image for reuse. [`BufferedImageOp.filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImageOp.html#filter-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-) supports a `null` destination image argument in order to create a new compatible image but the `AffineTransformOp` would create an image bigger than the source for angles like 45° which seems not what you want, given the code in your question.